# Horizontal scrollbar is not working with JTable in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have a `JTable` which I am passing in `JScrollPane`. The vertical scrollbar is showing up and working good, but the horizontal scrollbar is not working. The code I provided is compilable, just put your path in `InputFile1` string and create a long file on that location.

I have tried many solutions but nothing is working. I have a table with only one column, that column contains lines from a document. I need both vertical and horizontal scrollbars. Please suggest some solution.

Other attempts:

**Case1**:

```
tab.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
```

If I am setting this ,vertical scrollbar doesn't work.

**Case2:**

```
tab.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

If I set this, the column width becomes very small. If I try to make it larger then also it does not work and only shows a horizontal scroll bar but without a viewport.

You can uncomment and check them.

**Code:**

```
public class tablecreate extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{

    JPanel mainPanel;
    tablecreate() throws IOException
    {

        mainPanel=new JPanel();
        String InputFile1 = "/home/user/Desktop/a.txt";
        BufferedReader breader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(InputFile1));
        String line1 = "";
        line1 = breader1.readLine();
        DefaultTableModel model1 = new DefaultTableModel();
        JTable tab=new JTable(model1);
        model1.addColumn("line"); 
        while((line1=breader1.readLine()) != null)
         {
             System.out.println(line1);
             model1.addRow(new Object[]{line1});
         }
         breader1.close();
         tab.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(1,1));
         tab.setVisible(true);
        //tab.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        // tab.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF); 

         JScrollPane js = new JScrollPane(tab,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
         js.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
         mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
         mainPanel.setSize(500,500);
         mainPanel.add(js);
         this.add(mainPanel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        tablecreate tc=new tablecreate();
        tc.setSize(500,500);
        tc.setVisible(true);
        tc.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use:

```
table.setAutoResizeMode( JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF );
```

Don't use:

```
tab.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(1,1));
```

That is an unrealistic size. That method is to give a reasonable preferred size to the table so that the `frame.pack()` method will work.

> js.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));

Don't set the preferred size of the scrollpane. The `setPreferredScrollableViewportSize()` is used to specify a size for the table.

```
mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
mainPanel.setSize(500,500);
```

Don't set a size or a preferred size of a component. Each component is responsible for determining its own preferred size.

> mainPanel=new JPanel();

By default a JPanel uses a FlowLayout which means any component added to it is displayed at its preferred size. I would probably set the layout to a BorderLayout. Then the component can resize with the space available and the scrollbars will be used as required.

Edit:

The scrollbars appear when the preferred size of table is greater than the size of the scrollpane. So you need to set the width of the `TableColumn` based on the width of the text to be displayed in the column. An easy way to do this is to use the [Table Column Adjuster](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/) class which will set the width to the largest line of text. YOu would invoke this class after you have added the model (containing the data) to the table:

Updated code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TableCreate extends JFrame
{
    JPanel mainPanel;
    TableCreate() throws IOException
    {

        mainPanel=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        String InputFile1 = "TableCreate.java";
        BufferedReader breader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(InputFile1));
        String line1 = "";
        line1 = breader1.readLine();

        DefaultTableModel model1 = new DefaultTableModel();
        model1.addColumn("line");

        while((line1=breader1.readLine()) != null)
         {
             System.out.println(line1);
             model1.addRow(new Object[]{line1});
         }
         breader1.close();

        JTable tab=new JTable(model1);

        tab.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        tab.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        TableColumnAdjuster tca = new TableColumnAdjuster(tab);
        tca.adjustColumns();

        JScrollPane js = new JScrollPane(tab);
        add(js);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        TableCreate tc=new TableCreate();
        tc.pack();
        tc.setVisible(true);
        tc.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already used table.setAutoResizeMode( JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF ); and told the result.I am not using frame,so I can not use frame.pack() ,I am using JPanel only.

Comment: @user2769274, Yes you are using a JFrame. In order to display a panel you must add it to a JFrame (or JDialog or JWindow). In your case you are extending JFrame so you do add the panel to the frame. Instead of using `tc.setVisible(...)` you should be using `tc.pack()` and you need to make all the changes I suggest above. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for working example on how to properly create a frame with a table.

Comment: I followed all your suggestions,It is making the width of column smaller,the ViewPort for horizontal scrollbar is still not showing up.

Comment: If I am removing tc.setVisible(true);,the window is not coming up.even if i am putting tc.pack();